# Can I connect a child BU and leave the parent BU disconnected?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sfmc-business-unit

I am trying to set up Marketing Cloud Connect to my child Business Unit using an API User that is only assigned to that BU. Whenever I click on Connect Account on 'Salesforce Integration' within set up and log in using my CRM credentials, that connection then replicates in the parent BU (that should not be connected to that ORG) hence I do not have access to the Synchonized Data Sources in my child BU because we do not have Multi-Org enabled at this point.

Can I configure the MCC just to that child BU without having it also at the parent-level?

Comment: For that you would need multi-org enabled.

Answer (score 4):

If you truly want the DE to be "in the Child BU" (note the quotation marks*), indeed you would need multi-org. Then the synchronized DEs show up in the Child BU / Synchronized Data Extension folder, as opposed to the Parent BU / Synchronized Data Extension folder where they are normally located.

This problem: `I do not have access to the Synchronized Data Sources in my child BU because we do not have Multi-Org enabled at this point.` can be worked around.

I would advise to check that option before you switch to multi-org just for that, which you won't be able to reverse. This is from Trailhead at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-contact-management/explore-synchronized-data-sources, highlight by me:

> Segment Synced Data Extensions Across Business Units

> Most data extensions need to be segmented to create other audiences for sends. For example, Northern Trail Outfitters shares contact information with a business unit, but their security team doesn’t want the business unit to see all of the contact data. **The system segments the data, stores it in a shared folder, then shares it with other business units**.

The only, in my book, theoretical, downside to this is that your query will be running hourly, while the vanilla connector would stream every 15 mins.

===

*With Multi Org enabled:

even though it then looks as if the Synchronized DEs were located in the Child BU, they will still stay in parent physically, and you will need the ENT. prefix to query them.

This is also why in a multi-org setup, the synchronized data extensions get names like "Contact_Salesforce_1", _2, etc. after the first connection has been made.  - All the Synchronized DEs are actually still in Parent and run into a naming conflict after the first set has been synched and then occupies the "Contact_Salesforce" name.

here's what Trailhead says, and it's to be understood verbatim:

> **By default, data extensions containing synchronized data exist at the top level of an Enterprise tenant**. These data extensions cannot be moved into a shared folder. To segment the data extension, you need to use a query or filter activity that populates the information from a synchronized data source and moves the information into a shared data extension.

... and we can verify and test all that.

Screenshot taken from Child BU in a multi-Org Setup. It appears the Synched DEs are in Child BU:

[image]

The SQL query UI does not show the Synchronized DEs regardless of multi-org setup, but still you can access them.

Screenshot from the same Child BU in a Multi Org setup. even though we just saw the Synchronized DE in Child above, they don't show up here:

[image]

-> But, queries do work. again, screenshot from a Child BU inside a multi org system. This query is validating / running successfully:

[image]

Note how it uses the ENT. prefix.

It fails without the prefix, so clearly the Synchronized DE is still in Parent, even though only the Child BU Data Extension UI shows it.

[image]